# Existence of proper field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am wondering whether the following statement is true or not?

> Given any field $F$, there exists a proper field extension $K$ of $F$.

Comment: For analogy consider: let $\, k < j \, $ be naturals... Would you similarly ask: how do I know there is a natural $< j\,?$ Of course if $\,j = 0\,$ there is not. But then the theorem simply does not apply, since its hypotheses are not satisfied. Hypotheses make no implications about their satisfiability. Indeed, in proofs by contradiction one makes inferences about hypothetical nonexistent objects, e.g. the hypothetical "naturals with finitely many primes" in Euclid's proof done in contradiction form.

Comment: The field $\mathbb{C}(t)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$ in the indeterminate $t$, is a nontrivial extension of $\mathbb{C}$. Quotienting $F[x]$ by an irreducible polynomial is not the only way to create a field extension of a field $F$.

Comment: Ethan has answered your question, essentially. Just take $K = F(t)$, the field of rational functions in one indeterminate over your ground field $F$. (You posted your question at MO claiming that no one answered your question here; that's clearly not the case.)

Comment: @user43208 I thought his answer only applies to $\mathbb{C}$. What's the difference between $F(t)$ and $F[X]$? And if I want to another proper extension field of $F(t)$, I can just do $F(t)(t)$?

Comment: Two points: (1) Clearly the same principle generalizes from $\mathbb{C}$ to any field $F$. (2) Ethan wrote his comment before your edit, where your earlier version had made special mention of $\mathbb{C}$. To answer your question: $F(t)$ is the field of fractions of the integral domain $F[t]$. If you want to iterate this, adjoin a new indeterminate $x$ and form $F(t)(x) = F(t, x)$, the field of fractions of the integral domain $F[t, x]$ (polynomials in two indeterminates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you talk about the existence of field contain strictly F as sub
field , the answer  is yes, as indicated in the comments, with for
example $K = F (t)$ rational field of polinomial ring $F[t]$.

If you talk about finite extension $K$ over $F$,then  $K$ exist
 if and only if $F$ is not algebraically closed.

if you talk about a proper sub extension $K$ of $F$ , then  $K$
exist if and only if $F$ is not prime field ($\neq\Bbb{Q}$ and
$\neq\Bbb{F}_p$)